# Cache values in Angular nested loop

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following HTML code, notice that ng-show needs access to the same data as ng-repeat:

```
   <div ng-repeat="cat in getSelectedCategories()">

        <div ng-show="getFilteredQuestions(cat).hasItems">

            <div ng-repeat="(promptId, q) in getFilteredQuestions(cat).val">

                   // nested loop contents
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

notice that I am calling `getFilteredQuestions()` twice, and it should yield the exact same data, in fact it must yield the exact same data if I want the display to be consistent! Does AngularJS normally cache this call for us, or is there some trick we can use to cache the value since I am using it twice in the same loop.

What I am thinking is in the `getFilteredQuestions()`, setting a cached value on `$scope`, and the in the inner loop reading from that cached instead of calling `getFilteredQuestions()` again.

Comment: No, and No.  Angular expressions are executed every `$digest` cycle, and if the results of an expression call causes a model change, it could potentially cause *another* `$digest` cycle, and *another* evaluation of all the expressions.  Therefore, this is not the kind of logic that should be put in your templates.

Comment: i agree with Claies, should try to find some other way of filtering, avoid doing inlined in the template like that

Comment: Sorry I can't tell if you understood the question, I added some more info in the original question.

Comment: It actually seems you are advocating for my suggesting to cache the value instead of calling `getFilteredQuestions()`

Comment: your suggestion is a reasonable theory, but you will likely have issues with using `$scope`;  you'll end up having to use an array to cache each branch of the outer loop for use in the inner loop, and you'll *still* be running a function every `$digest` to update each branch to the same value;  Instead, you should actually structure the data the way you want to display it *in the `.then()` of the original data fetch*.

Comment: Yeah I added an answer, and it seems to work, and I listed the benefits. It's somewhat the antithesis of functional programming, but if you need the same data twice, making two different calls in a stateful application is probably not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so caching values *does seem to work*, as I expected it to. Is probably (1) more performant, (2) avoids "infinite digest cycles", and (3) ensures data consistency.

basically, we have this now, instead of what's in the OP:

```
 <div ng-repeat="cat in getSelectedCategories()">

         <div ng-show="getFilteredQuestions(cat)">

            <div ng-repeat="(promptId, q) in getFilteredQuestionsCache(cat)">

                   // nested loop contents
            </div>
         </div>
  </div>
```

notice the second call is not to `getFilteredQuestions() but to`getFilteredQuestionsCache()`.

when `getFilteredQuestions()` is called, it updates the cache property in the controller like so:

```
$scope.getFilteredQuestions = function(){

   // ...
   $scope.filteredQuestionsCache[cat] = obj; //update the cache
   return Object.keys(obj).length > 0;  // for the ng-show decision
};
```

and `getFilteredQuestionsCache()` is like so:

```
 $scope.getFilteredQuestionsCache = function (cat) {
    return $scope.filteredQuestionsCache[cat];
  };
```

In this way, ng-show and ng-repeat do not repeat a call to get the same data.